# Paypal sandbox Payment Data Transfer

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I have a problem with paypal sandbox 'Payment Data Transfer'.
After recieve the tansaction Id, I am sending it back to paypal with Identity tocken to get the transaction details.

I have followed this document 'http://media.albendas.com/Web2py_Paypal_Integration.pdf'.

```
password_mgr= urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
base_url='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com'
header = {'Content-Type ':' application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
path = '/cgi-bin/webscr'
data = "cmd=_notify-synch&tx="+trans+"&at="+key
password_mgr.add_password(self.realm,base_url,self.username,self.password)
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener =urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
req=urllib2.Request(base_url+path,data,header)
ret = opener.open(req)
```

normally I should get a message either SUCCESS of FAIL. But for me always getting the return page as 
We are unable to complete your request at this time. Please click Retry or try again later. We apologize for the inconvenience.
Message 3004.

Plese advise.
Also please let me know, what is the realm parameter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same code is working fine with actual paypal (instead of sandbox).  I have no idea why this same code is not working on sandbox.